# How to make CSS dropshadow with offset around sides

Tags: css

I want to make a dropshadow that has no blur and has slight offset around the sides and also is rounded corners. Exactly like the image below

[image: Image with dropshadow]

Any alternative approach besides dropshadows might also work aswell

Comment: Google much? http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

Add these to the element's CSS:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 10px rgba(236,245,159,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 10px rgba(236,245,159,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 10px rgba(236,245,159,1);
```

Example:

```css
#box {
    margin:40px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:20px;
    background-color:#E8ED8A;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 10px rgba(236,245,159,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 10px rgba(236,245,159,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 10px rgba(236,245,159,1);
}
```

```html
<div id='box'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box{
width:80px;
height:80px;
background-color:red;
border-radius:10px;
border: 1px offset red;
box-shadow:5px 5px 0px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```